# Web Page Not Found - HTTP 404, ASP.NET page isn't working with IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a new Web page on our IIS7.5 server. I am using the same settings as an existing and working site, but the new one isn't working.
If it's runing or not, I get the same error, as if it's not even there:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /HomePage.aspx

What am I missing?

Thanks
GZ

---

It now works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, but NOT on IE.

It uses Windows authentification. On IE9, I get asked my credentials a few times before getting the 401-Not authorised page.

Why does it work on the other 3 broswers and not this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure IIS and WebSite are both started.

Comment: Everything is started. I have a working site on the same IIS.

Comment: Strange. Also verify that .NET is enabled for that site and the version of .NET is correct.

Comment: Is there a specific place where I should check that .NET is enabled for that site? It was working well on my computer while developing with VS.

Comment: It seemed that it was a DNS problem. oups. The IT guy said he double-checked it, but a triple-check was necessary.

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem was resolved. Yeah triple-check beats double-check anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn your WebSite in a application, on IIS. You'll find it in properties of website, Home Directory tab, Applications settings. If you find a Create button (click on it).

Also verify execution permission. Set it to Scripts Only.